# Capturing bookmark in Power Bi Embedded in React

Tags: reactjs, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to implement bookmark capture feature in our Application. I cloned the https://github.com/howlowck/react-powerbi library to extend it with such functionality. Based on MS Demo and documentation there is a method .capture() on bookmarksManager object. Here is my code modifications trying to access this (file index.js of this library):

```
componentDidUpdate () {
    if (this.validateConfig(this.state)) {
      this.embed(this.state)
      console.log(this.component.bookmarksManager)
      getBookmark(this.component)
  }
}
...
function getBookmark(power){
  console.log('inside getBookmark')
  console.log(power.bookmarksManager.capture)
 power.bookmarksManager.capture().then (function (capturedBookmark){
    alert('inside callback')

  });
  console.log('passed test')
      
    }
```

When running - console.log displays 'inside bookmark' also displays capture function but the callback is never executed. (Nor any uncaught promise rejections) Any helpful ideas?

The function exists in library:

```
BookmarksManager.prototype.capture = function () {
            if (utils.isRDLEmbed(this.config.embedUrl)) {
                return Promise.reject(errors.APINotSupportedForRDLError);
            }
            return this.service.hpm.post("/report/bookmarks/capture", null, { uid: this.config.uniqueId }, this.iframe.contentWindow)
                .then(function (response) { return response.body; }, function (response) {
                throw response.body;
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

After thorough debugging including powerbi.js file it seems that the call is placed to early and config is null resulting in { uid: this.config.uniqueId } being undefined. The same function placed under component will unmount gets called successfully. Probably the library  has to be modified in the way that it accepts callback as a prop. This callback should accept "power" object. After successful embedding the parent component can capture and/or apply bookmarks on e.g. some button actions.